# Não consigo rodar meu projeto em react native no meu celular

Tags: react, react-native, mobile

Estou criando uma aplicação em react native, que é um projeto de uma pokedex, que recebe informações da API do pokemon e mostra na tela as informações. Não estou conseguindo usar o meu celular para vizualizar como a aplicação está ficando.

Já instalei o node, chocolatey, java, android studio e o yarn. Estou usando o yarn no terminal para tentar rodar o projeto.

estou usando os seguintes comandos dentro do terminal do vscode:

`yarn`

`yarn start`

abro outro terminal (ainda dentro do vscode)

`adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`

`yarn android`

aí me surge o seguinte erro:

```
yarn run v1.22.18
$ react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 936 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Adriano José\adriano\mobileapppokemon\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Adriano José\adriano\mobileapppokemon\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Adriano Jos�\adriano\mobileapppokemon\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 213

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Adriano JosÃ©\adriano\mobileapppokemon\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: 
[]}

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Adriano José\adriano\mobileapppokemon\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Adriano José\adriano\mobileapppokemon\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Adriano Jos�\adriano\mobileapppokemon\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 213

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Adriano JosÃ©\adriano\mobileapppokemon\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: 
[]}

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

    at makeError (C:\Adriano José\adriano\mobileapppokemon\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Adriano José\adriano\mobileapppokemon\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Adriano José\adriano\mobileapppokemon\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Adriano José\adriano\mobileapppokemon\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Tem uma ferramenta chamada EXPO, serve para criar aplicativos mobile para IOS, Android e Web, utilizando React Native, acredito que esse erro não vai ocorrer utilizando esta ferramenta, da uma pesquisar sobre ela

Answer (score -2):

Fala Adriano,

Acredito que o seu erro está ocorrendo bem aqui:

```
^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Adriano JosÃ©\adriano\mobileapppokemon\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'
```

Perceba que o seu caminho possui um caminho com caractere especial, nesse caso, o `é` do `Adriano José`.

Alterando para um caminho que não possua esse caractere especial (ex.: `C:\adriano\mobileapppokemon`) resolverá o problema o app funcionará normalmente.

Espero ter ajudado.